# On mobile view, replace burger menu item with phone number only on specific page (lead form)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm looking to make our lead form page have fewer distractions, by removing the menu bar.
I have managed to do this using CSS.

On desktop, our phone number shows at the top left of the screen which is great and we want to keep, however on mobile the smaller "burger" menu still shows.

I have managed to remove this using:

```
.page-id-547 .navbar-toggler {display:none; }
```

and

However when on mobile view I want it to show our phone number as a clickable button instead of just on this specific page.

```
href="tel:+44800********" class="btn btn-orange text-dark-blue"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> 0800 *** ***
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to edit the html? If so add a separate link with the phone number and then hide it from desktop using a css media query such as this one

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    #new-phone-link{ display:none; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kirill. I don't think I can edit the HTML, or if i can i'm not sure how! 

I was hoping there was some kind of CSS code i could write that basically said:

Replace burger menu

```.page-id-547 .navbar-toggler {display:none; }```

with ```fas fa-phone-alt```

Comment: Well technically you can. `fas` applies a set of styles, `fa-phone-alt` does too. So figure out what they apply, copy that into your declaration (everything between `{}`) and you're gold.